# Does Frobenius number increase if bound on input increases?

Tags: nt.number-theory, computer-science, automata-theory

The Frobenius number F is the largest number not expressible as a non-negative linear combination of some set of positive integers $\{a_i\}$, where, $a_i$ has gcd 1. Denote $maxF(n)$ as the maximum of F over the set of positive integers, such that

1. $a_i$'s are distinct
2. $a_i < n$

Is it true that $F(n) < F(n+1)$?

For context, I am trying to analyse the structure of a non deterministic finite automaton over a unary alphabet in Chrobak Normal Form.

Comment: $ F(2) = F(3) $.

Comment: For $n\ge4$, $F(n)=(n-2)(n-3)-1=n^2-5n+5$: on the one hand, this is the Frobenius number of $\{n-1,n-2\}$. On the other hand, if $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ is any set with $\gcd(\vec a)=1$ and $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_k<n$, then its Frobenius number is at most $(a_1-1)(a_k-1)-1\le(n-2)(n-3)-1$ by Schur’s bound (see e.g. Proposition 2.2 in https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis5110/Frobenius-number.pdf).